# MongoDB replication when access control is enabled

Tags: mongodb, nosql, database-replication, replicaset

I have 2 servers where the MongoDB database is installed.
Both servers have enabled database access control by creating users.
Now, I need to make replication for these servers. One for primary and the other for secondary.

I followed https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/

But above reference URL steps have been for when access control is disabled.

Need MongoDB replication steps when access control is already enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Actually nothing changes. You only have to provide username/password when you connect to the database, the rest is identical.

However, you may follow [Deploy Replica Set With Keyfile Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-keyfile-access-control/). Just go from item 1 up to 5, then it should be done.

Anyway, for me it is not clear what you try to do. You write you have 2 existing MongoDB servers. Are they different?

Do you like to put these two different databases into one new Replica Set? In a Replica Set the SECONDARY is an **exact** copy of the PRIMARY, so you cannot push data from 2 different sources into PRIMARY and SECONDARY.

Comment: When auth is enabled, the nodes must authenticate to each other if I am remembering correctly (e.g. via key file).

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I have 2 mongodb servers. Both are different. I have 1 database, and need to replicate dat between these 2 servers.